# Regex to match dynamic name once

Tags: regex

I want to match a company name once from a string that looks like [this](https://regexr.com/652v7)

What I want: `Distribution Services Management` only once

What I get `CATE-N LUNA SI-N STELE SRL`

What I'm trying `Client\n+(.*?[ ]\s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
Client\n{2}.*\s{5}(.*)
```

My Logic is:

1. The desired string is always after Client's down the next two-line, i.e. lies at third line.
2. Before the start of our desired string there are some spaces(I assumed atleast 5)
3. After those 5 spaces until the next newline is what our desired output lies.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GeGo3v/2

Comment: @shAkur: is this helping?

Comment: There is no need to put \n in character classes.

Comment: Agree @Alireza!! Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\s` could also match a newline, and in the example data it looks like there are 2 or more spaces before the part that you want to match.

The reason you get capture `CATE-N LUNA SI-N STELE SRL` in group 1 is because  you start the match after the newline without matching the part after the 2 spaces.

You could use

```
\bClient\n+.*[^\S\r\n]{2}(\S.*)
```

In parts, the pattern matches

- `\bClient\n+`
- `.*[^\S\r\n]{2}` Match until the end of the string, and backtrack to the last occurrence (or use `\n+.*?` for the first occurrence) of 2 whitespace chars except a newline
- `(\S.*)` Capture **group 1**, match at least a single non whitespace char followed by optional chars except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kSOBQd/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
(?<=  \b).*(?=\n CIF)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eKbGIJ/1)

The way I solved this was to check the desired word between many spaces and the word CIF in the next line. I thought two spaces in `(?<=  \b)` would be enough.

`(?<=  \b)` part is to check at least two spaces and the word boundry. `(?=\n CIF)` part is positive lookahead assertion to check if it is before CIF in the next line.